# Saturators similar to URS Saturator (without ilok requirement)

Tags: mixing, post-production, production, production-audio

Disappointed in the need for ilok with URS software, the saturator is what i'm after, multiple models/algorithms, a saturation amount knob as well as in/out gain control.

I'm looking for a saturator that can increase loudness perception while reducing the peak amount like the way URS saturation does.

Does anyone have any suggestions for any other saturators that can do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Ferric TDS is one of the most known and awarded freeware plugin.

https://www.kvraudio.com/product/ferrictds---tape-dynamics-simulator-by-variety-of-sound

To me it's a very subtle effect , but it can get you in the world of good (as good as the digital domain can be in non linear effects) saturation!

Be sure to give it a try.

For more complex stuff , i use badbussmojo , a stillwell plugin that's good , cheap , and has an evaluation version too!

http://www.stillwellaudio.com/plugins/bad-buss-mojo/

Good luck!